# JAVASCRIPT - Не могу вывести условие с временем. В консоль выводит Доброй ночи Роман, даже если верно другое условие

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

1.В консоль выводит Доброй ночи Роман, даже если верно другое условие

2.Написать функцию, которой передаем имя, и она возвращает приветствие в зависимости от времени суток (Доброе утро\день\вечер\ночи Иван) - само задание, которое я пытаюсь выполнить

```
let time1 = new Date('September 21, 2021 20:46:00 +0700');
function setTime(name, time) {
  if (12 > time >= 4) {
    console.log(`Доброе утро ${name}`);
  } else if (20 > time >= 12){
    console.log(`Добрый день ${name}`);
  } else if (23 > time >= 20){
    console.log(`Добрый вечер ${name}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Доброй ночи ${name}`);
  }
}
setTime("Роман", time1.getHours())
```

Comment: а сколько раз можно сравнения в строке писать? можно например сразу `1 > x > 2 > y > 3 > z` ?

Comment: @teran Сколько хочешь. Только результат будет не тот, который ждешь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё верно. Потому что двойных условных выражений в языке нет.

Вот например `12 > time >= 4`. Да, возможно, в математике можно сказать, что `time` меньше 12 и больше или равно 4. Но в языке таких конструкций нет. Замена такому будет

```
time < 12 && time >=4
```

---

**Небольшое дополнение**:

Окей. Язык позволяет писать такие условия, но результат выполнения будет не тот, что ожидается. И он немного отличен от тех, что есть в математике.

Если конкретно на одном примере:

```
if (12 > time >= 4) {
```

В условии `12 > time` результатом будет `true` или `false`. Потому что фактически мы как бы виртуально спрашиваем "time меньше 12?". Ответом может быть да или нет. Дальше этот самый `true/false` идёт в сопоставление с 4. При сравнении булевого типа и числового, первый приводится к числу и потом только производится вычисление. `true` приводится к числу 1, `false` к 0.
В итоге будет либо `1 >= 4` либо `0 >= 4`. Результатом этого выражения опять будет булево. И оно будет всегда `false`. Итог `if (12 > time >= 4)` будет `false` всегда.

Аналогично можно посмотреть другие условия.

Comment: Друг, спасибо!!!

Comment: формально то конструкция имеет место быть но вернет false

Comment: @teran да я хотел вначале написать, что писать-то можно, но получим не то, что ожидаем, но потом подумал, что лучше сказать "нельзя" и тогда человек не станет в принципе их писать, что будет я считаю верным) Ведь так может и пишет кто, но 0.001% ))

Comment: я к тому, что возможно было бы неплохо пояснить, что первая часть time < 12 принимает булевое значение, которое затем приводится к 1 или 0, и оставшаяся часть 0/1 >=4 возвращает false,а то он так и не поймет, что произошло.

Comment: @teran хорошо, дополнил

Comment: @Roman дополнил пояснением до конца.  Чтобы было ясно почему так происходит в итоге